# Swift shows nil value for Dictionary type

Tags: ios, swift

I have a dictionary of type `< String, String>`. It can access by index values like `dictionary[0]`. But i want to access each values in this in a simple way by using the key.

```
 var rows: [Dictionary<String, String>] = []
 rows = [..] // assigned some value
 var value = rows[0]["id"]
 println(rows[0]) // ["id": "2", "name": "Bob", "age": "19"]
 println(value) // I get nil value
```

How can i access by this key format. Any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

I tried to read values from a CSV file. And assigned to rows. It works fine when i print `rows[0]` it shows the correct value. But on the next line if i print `rows[0]["id"]` it gives me a nil value. And i tried with manual dictionary like

```
     rows =  [["name": "alvin"]]  
     var value = rows[0]["name"] 
     println(value) // prints alvin
```

Whats the difference?

Comment: can you show how you assign the values? your code works fine for me

Comment: @kap Question modified.

Comment: `rows = [["id": "2", "name": "Bob", "age": "19"]]
var value = rows[0]["id"]
println(rows[0])
println(value)` works fine for me

Answer (score 1):

This could happen if your key has a space in it.  Consider the following:

```
var rows: [Dictionary<String, String>] = []
rows = [["id ": "2", "name": "Bob", "age": "19"]] // assigned some value
var value = rows[0]["id"]
println(rows[0]) // ["id": "2", "name": "Bob", "age": "19"]
println(value) // I get nil value
```

To check your keys, print them out like this to see if there is any space in them:

```
for key in rows[0].keys {
    println("XXX\(key)XXX")
}
```

prints:

```
XXXid XXX
XXXageXXX
XXXnameXXX
```

showing that key `id` is followed by a space, but `age` and `name` are not.